# Xamarin color part of a TextView

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, textview

I want my `TextView` in my `ViewSwitcher` to switch colors between green and white every new line. I figure out how to change the color, but only of the entire `TextView` with the method:

```
SetTextColor()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want my TextView in my ViewSwitcher to switch colors between green and white every new line. I figure out how to change the color, but only of the entire TextView

You can use `TextFormatted` together with `Android.Text.SpannableString` to set the color:

```
int lineCount = tvResult.LineCount;
SpannableString spannableText =new SpannableString(tvResult.Text);
for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
{
   int start=tvResult.Layout.GetLineStart(i);
   int end = tvResult.Layout.GetLineEnd(i);
   if (i % 2 == 1)
   {
       spannableText.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow), start, end, SpanTypes.Composing);
   }
   else
   {
       spannableText.SetSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Android.Graphics.Color.Green), start, end,SpanTypes.Composing);
   }
}
tvResult.TextFormatted = spannableText;
```

Notes: tvResult is just a TextView control.

Comment: Thank you, it works! I had to use the full class name, though, so it was `Android.Text.Style.ForegroundColorSpan` and `Android.Text.SpanTypes.Composing`

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use TextFormatted property of the TextView. Some sample you can find on Xamarin forums: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9403/setting-a-textview-to-a-spannable-string

Comment: Where can i find this property?

Comment: Did you tried to search documentation? https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Widget.TextView.TextFormatted/